# Parsing key value pairs as Hive Dataset rows using java spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I have a hdfs file with the following data

```
key1=value1  key2=value2  key3=value3...
key1=value11  key2=value12   key3=value13..
```

We use and internal framework that gives Dataset as an input to java method which should be transformed as below and put in a hive table

1. keys should be the hive column names
2. Row formed after splitting the dataset with = as delimiter and picking the value to the right

Expected Output:

```
key1      | key 2       | key3
----------+-------------+----------              
value1    | value2      | value3                 
value11   | value12     | value13
```

Hdfs file would roughly have 60 key- value pairs so its impossible to manually do a withcolumn() on Dataset. Any help is appreciated.

Edit1:
This is what I could write so far. Dataset.withColumn() doesnt seem to be working in a loop except for the 1st iteration

```
    String[] columnNames = new String[dataset.columns().length];
    String unescapedColumn;
    Row firstRow= (Row)dataset.first();

    String[] rowData = firstRow.mkString(",").split(",");
    for(int i=0;i<rowData.length;i++) {
        unescapedColumn=rowData[i].split("=")[0];
        if(unescapedColumn.contains(">")) {
            columnNames[i] = unescapedColumn.substring(unescapedColumn.indexOf(">")+1).trim();
        }else {
            columnNames[i] = unescapedColumn.trim();
        }
    }
    Dataset<Row> namedDataset = dataset.toDF(columnNames);
    for(String column : namedDataset.columns()) {
        System.out.println("Column name :" + column);
        namedDataset = namedDataset.withColumn(column, functions.substring_index(namedDataset.col(column),"=",-1));
    }
```

Comment: If you have enough use of this kind of files perhaps you can look at writing your own file format

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera not sure wat u meant. Are u suggesting using an Encoder and save the custom object in Hive ?

Comment: A file format is just an inherited class, extended from `TextBasedFileFormat`. You provide methods to infer schemas, read and writing rows, and then you use it as any other file format in Spark. It's easy enough, with no previous experience it took me about one day of reading through code to come up with one for my case (which was very similar to yours). Have a look at the [Spark sources](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources).